# Questions on probability law

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following true or false statements, and I want to know if they are correct

> 1. For every measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$ is always well defined

Answer: False. Choose a RV in $\mathbb{Z}$ then the expected value $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]=\sum\limits_{\mathbb{Z}}g(x)f_x(x)$ is not well-defined since we do not know in which order we summate.

> 2. If $P(X=t)=P(Y=t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $P(X=Y)=1$

Answer: False. Choose two continuous random variable $X,Y:=-X$ then $P(X=t)=P(Y=t)=0$ for every discrete point but $P(X=Y)=0$

> 3. If $P(X\leq t)=P(Y\leq t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $P(X=Y)=1$

Answer: False. Choose two continuous random variable $X,Y$ such that $Y=-X$ then $P(X\leq t)=P(Y\leq t)=0$ for every discrete point but $P(X=Y)=0$

> 4. If $P(X = t)=P(Y = t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same law

Answer: False. Choose two arbitrary continuous random variables which have $P(X=t)=P(Y=t)=0$ for any discrete value. But this does not imply $P(X\leq n)= P(Y\leq n)$

> 5. If $X$ and $Y$ have the same law and $X\geq 0$ a.s. then $Y\geq 0$ a.s

This I don't know

> 6. If $X$ and $Y$ have the same law and $P(X< Y)=P(X>Y)$

True. $P(X<Y)=P(\frac{X}{Y}<1)$ and $P(X>Y)=P(\frac{Y}{X}<1)$ Let $g(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$, then $E[f(X,Y)]=E[f(X,Y)]=\int g(x)f(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is the density function.

Thanks for answering

Comment: I find many of your arguments unconvincing, especially (3) and (6), while for (2) I think need the word *symmetric*

Comment: What is (6), already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) You do not need to set $Y = -X$. The statement is false in general for continuous random variables. If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables then $\mathbb{P}(X= t) = \mathbb{P}(Y = t) = 0$ for any $t$. Of course, this does not imply that $X = Y$ a.s

(3) This statement is indeed false. I would suggest to find a counter example. This does not have to be very complex. Try for instance $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X= 1) = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y = 0) = \mathbb{P}(Y = 1) = 1/2$ independent r.v. Then $\mathbb{P}(X=Y) = 1/2$.

(5) $X$ and $Y$ have the saw law (i.e same distribution), that is, $F_X(t) = F_Y(t), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, $X \geq 0$ a.s is equivalent with $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0) = 1$ or equivalently $F_X(0) = 0$. Thus?